# Getting protected HTML fields when using Excel VBA and CreateObject("htmlfile")

Tags: excel, vba

When using the following VBA code to get HTML from a https website I get obfuscated HTML content as "****" instead of name even though I am passing username and pass as parameters using method: xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False, username, pass:

```
        Set xml_obj = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Set html_doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        xml_obj.Open "GET", my_url, False, "Username", "Pass"
        xml_obj.send
        pageSource = xml_obj.responseText
```

Here is some string result I get:

full_name":"***** *****","address":"***** *****","city":"******","state":"*****","zip":"*****","relatives":["***** *****","***** *****","***** *****","***** *****","*****

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It sounds like you still have a problem with your `GET` url and the API of the website. I think you'll need some help that is specific to that website and possibly to your account type.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your reply.
So, when I login into the source website and check the source code I see all the code. Do you have a code I can use to read the source code of a HTTPS website that requires a login?